# Laravel NPM Package | Cannot Access the Package

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-5.8

Long story short. I've installed a package via NPM into a Laravel Application. I have run `npm run dev`, which has built successfully; I have also run `npm run watch` while developing the application.

I have also put this line in the `app.js` file:
`import Push from 'push.js';`

And I have included the:
`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

line into my main template file.

However I'm still getting this error:
`Push is not defined`

When trying to use the package.

([Here is the package](https://pushjs.org/docs/quick-start))

(Laravel 5.8)

Comment: Show us where you're *using* Push.

Comment: @ceejayoz Javascript is in a `main.blade.php` file under the `Resources` folder >> `Javscript` folder >> `main.blade.php`. Push is included in the `app.blade.php` template file. Which is including the `app.js` file (where Push is being imported) before the `main.blade.php` file so it's not an ordering issue if that's what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to use it *outside* of your `app.js` (and its children via `import` or `require`), like in a Blade template, you probably need to do `window.Push = Push` in your `app.js` to make it available globally. You can see this in Laravel's default install [in the `resources/js/bootstrap.js`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js). For example:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```